# Collect values from an api more quickly

Tags: python, json, api

To collect the values of an api, I use three loopings, I would like to know if it is possible to improve this method that I use.

```
a = 9625897
```

```
def graph(a):
    url = f'https://api.sofascore.com/api/v1/event/{a}/graph'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=1).json()
    if 'graphPoints' in response:
        minutes_list = [d['minute'] for d in response['graphPoints'][-5:]]
        value_list = [d['value'] for d in response['graphPoints'][-5:]]
        sum_list = sum(abs(d['value']) for d in response['graphPoints'][-5:])
    else:
        minutes_list = ['graph_error']
        value_list = ['graph_error']
        sum_list = ['graph_error']
    return [minutes_list,value_list,sum_list]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a conventional for loop, instead of comprehensions:

```
    minutes_list = []
    value_list = []
    value_sum = 0
    if 'graphPoints' in response:
        for d in response['graphPoints'][-5:]:
            minutes_list.append(d['minute'])
            value_list.append(d['value'])
            value_sum += abs(d['value'])
        return [minutes_list, value_list, [value_sum]]
    else:
        return [['graph_error'], ['graph_error'], ['graph_error']]
```

Comment: if you reverse the first and last statement you can dedent the code a bit, amking it easier to read